# PHP prevent CSRF attack

Tags: php, security

I'm raising the security levels of a software I'm working on.

The goal, as stated in the title, is to prevent CSRF attacks.

In a scenario that involves the use of the backend by a user who has to manage a control panel, let's take the example that the user must initialize a command that deletes a data from the database, obviously if it were used:

```
<a href="delete_post.php?post=003">Delete Post</a>
```

it would be an announced suicide.

By reading the PHP documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)

I found this that interested me a lot but it also made me ask questions.

If you implement the code in it:

```
function RandomToken($length = 32){
    if(!isset($length) || intval($length) <= 8 ){
        $length = 32;
    }
    if (function_exists('random_bytes')) {
        return bin2hex(random_bytes($length));
    }
    if (function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv')) {
        return bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    }
    if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length));
    }
}

function Salt(){
    return substr(strtr(base64_encode(hex2bin(RandomToken(32))), '+', '.'), 0, 44);
}

$token =  (RandomToken())."\n".Salt()."\n";
```

we will get such a thing that every time the page is refreshed it will change:

```
13356ac7fc5e058b61bbad693d84ca2e1d9ae584db356dfa928098800d46ed6d F0ToG948CsaUF2wGDSdt.DuyUMKY1VC/liEAyjTB6ME=
```

Which is good ...

but:

- If you choose the way of storing codes in the db and check that the generated code is new and never used then I validate the query statements for the elimination, who guarantees me that a user with bad intentions cannot generate the same 108-character code that maybe it has never been used?
- So a solution of a unique time code would be better?

How to solve this?

Comment: _"who guarantees me that a user with bad intentions cannot generate the same 108-character code that maybe it has never been used?"_ - are you talking about an absolutely-against-all-odds attempt at _guessing_ a correct code?

Comment: Nothing wrong with `delete_post.php?post=003` so long as you testing that only the owner (or an Admin) of that post can delete it and making that request. You might be making a solution to a problem that does not exitis.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your questions:

> If you choose the way of storing codes in the db (...)

Why store the codes in the DB? Store them in the users session. You can have one anti-CSRF token for the whole session and it makes handling of the token easier.

> who guarantees me that a user with bad intentions cannot generate the same 108-character code that maybe it has never been used?

Math. 32 byte random variable has an entropy of 256 bits. 128 bits would be sufficient to prevent a successful brute force attack and this is way above this.

> So a solution of a unique time code would be better?

No. You already have all you need. And you don't need salt for the purpose of token creation too.